# How to search different Keywords of different country's against two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns `Reason1, Reason2` both are Non full text search columns and don't have indexes also.
I have to search,

- if columns contains keywords like

  `'Investment','donation','charity','contribution'`. and these keywords might contain in `Spanish,ITALIAN,... like 7 countries`.

**How to search Multilanguage keywords against two columns ?**

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Show some example data: both that should match and that shouldn't.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Try the following variant

```
DECLARE @words varchar(100)='Investment,donation,charity,contribution'

-- put all the words into #words
-- you can use STRING_SPLIT if your version of SQL Server is 2016
;WITH wordsCTE AS(
  SELECT
    WordList,
    1 StartPosition,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',WordList)>0 THEN CHARINDEX(',',WordList) ELSE LEN(WordList)+1 END CommaPos,
    1 WordNum
  FROM (SELECT @words WordList) w

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    i.WordList,
    c.CommaPos+1 StartPosition,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',c.WordList,c.CommaPos+1)>0 THEN CHARINDEX(',',c.WordList,c.CommaPos+1) ELSE LEN(c.WordList)+1 END CommaPos,
    c.WordNum+1
  FROM (SELECT @words WordList) i
  CROSS JOIN wordsCTE c
  WHERE c.CommaPos<LEN(c.WordList)
)
SELECT '%'+SUBSTRING(WordList,StartPosition,CommaPos-StartPosition)+'%' word,WordNum
INTO #words
FROM wordsCTE

SELECT *
FROM #words

SELECT *
FROM [your table name is here] d
WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM #words w
          WHERE (d.Reason1 LIKE w.word OR d.Reason2 LIKE w.word)
        )

DROP TABLE #words
```

But I don't know how it'll be fast in your case.